# How to find a string of multiple line in shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I want to find the string

```
Time series prediction with ensemble models
```

in a pdf fle using shell script.I am using `pdftotext "$file" - | grep "$string"`.where `$file` is the pdf file name and `$string` is the above string.It can find out the line if the entire string contains in a line.but it can't find out line like:

```
Time series prediction with 
ensemble models
```

how can I resolve it.I am new to linux. so explanation in detail is appreciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way might be to replace `grep` by `pcregrep` (available from the 'universe' repository), which supports multiline matches, and then instead of searching for the literal string

```
Time series prediction with ensemble models
```

search instead for the [perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html)

```
Time\s+series\s+prediction\s+with\s+ensemble\s+models
```

where `\s+` stands for *one or more whitespace characters* (including newlines). Using the bash shell's built-in string substitution capabilities to perform the latter step

```
pdftotext "$file" - | pcregrep -M "${string// /\\s+}"
```

---

If you can't use `pcregrep` then you might be able to get the output you want using plain `grep` with the `-z` switch: this tells `grep` to consider the input "lines" to be delimited by `NUL` characters rather than newlines - in this case, effectively making it treat the whole input as a single line. So for example if you only want to print the matches (without context)

```
pdftotext "$file" - | grep -zPo "${string// /\\s+}"
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python, *a lot* can be done...

If I look at it again later, I will probably be able to do some optimization, but in my tests, the script below does the job.

Tested on a file:

```
Monkey eats banana since he ran out of peanuts 
Monkey
eats banana since he ran 
out of peanuts 
really, Monkey eats banana since 
he ran out of peanuts 
A lot of useless text here…
Have to add some lines for the sake of the test.
Monkey eats banana since he ran out of peanuts
```

looking for a string "Monkey eats banana since he ran out of peanuts", it outputs:

```
Found matches
--------------------
[line 1]
Monkey eats banana since he ran out of peanuts
[line 2]
Monkey
eats banana since he ran
out of peanuts
[line 5]
Monkey eats banana since
he ran out of peanuts
[line 9]
Monkey eats banana since he ran out of peanuts
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]; string = sys.argv[2]

# convert to .txt with your suggestion
subprocess.call(["pdftotext", f])
# read the converted file
text = open(f.replace(".pdf", ".txt")).read()
# editing the file a bit for searching options / define th length of the searched string
subtext = text.replace("\n", " "); size = len(string)
# in a while loop, find the matching string and set the last found index as a start for the next match
matches = []; start = 0
while True:
    match = subtext.find(string, start)
    if match == -1:
        break
    else:
        matches.append(match)
    start = match+1

print("Found matches\n"+20*"-")
for m in matches:
    # print the found matches, replacing the edited- in spaces by (possibly) original \n
    print("[line "+str(text[:m].count("\n")+1)+"]\n"+text[m:m+size].strip())
```

#### To use it:

1. copy the script into an empty file, save it as `search_pdf.py`
2. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/search_pdf.py /path/to/file.pdf string_to_look_for
   ```

No need to mention you need to use quotes if either the path or the searched string includes spaces:

```
python3 '/path to/search_pdf.py' '/path to/file.pdf' 'string to look for'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach suggested by steeldriver in the comments is to replace all line breaks with spaces, converting the output of `pdftotext` into one long line and searching that:

```
string="Time series prediction with ensemble models"
pdftotext "$file" - | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -o "$string"
```

I added the `-o` to make `grep` only print the matched portion of the line. Without it, you would get the entire contents of the file printed.

---

Another approach would be to use `grep`'s `-z` switch which tells it to use `\0` instead of `\n` to define lines. This means the entire input will be treated as a single "line" and you can use Perl compatible, or extended regular expressions to match it:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' | grep -oPz 'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
```

This, however, won't help unless you know before hand how the string has been split into multiple lines.

Comment: Which is exactly my concept, then in the found indexes restore the otiginal linebreaks.

Comment: @JacobVlijm it might be but it's also 18 lines of code and needs to be saved as a script. It is surprisingly fast though, I just tested it and was pleasantly surprised. I even upvoted a python answer for once! :P

Comment: Ah, thanks :) most of the lines are explanation though :)

Comment: No, I discarded comments and shebang line. Those are 18 lines of commands. But hey, we've had this discussion often enough, you always think writing an external script is the solution I always try to avoid it :)

Comment: Using `grep -z` would be another way to do this I think (it would effectively treat the whole input as a single "line", ignoring newlines).

Comment: @steeldriver that doesn't seem to work, no. That doesn't tell `grep` to expect null-delimited input, if that's what you thought.

Comment: @terdon hmm... I thought that's *exactly* what it does, no? From the manpage *"Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline"*. But I realize now it's equivalent to *removing* newlines rather than replacing them with spaces (as your solution does).

Comment: @steeldriver you're quite right, sorry. I thought it was equivalent to `zgrep` for some reason. In any case, I don't think it touches newlines at all, it just uses `\0` as a line terminator so it will treat the entire file as a single line. Therefore, it will only be useful if you already know how your search string has been split across multiple lines. Clever trick though, thanks, I added it to my answer.