# How to find a string in files, said string including line breaks, ", @

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I know grep allows me to search for a string in files, however I did not manage to find the right method to search for the following string:

```
  "snapshot3" : {
    "@custom_name" : true
```

So the string I am looking for contains one line break, quotation marks, the at sign @...

Any idea how I could look for exactly this string in text files ?!
Alternatively, it would be enough for me if I could search for files wherein there is only 2 or 3 words separating 'snapshot3' from 'true'

Comment: Really it should only be the line break that presents a challenge - see for example [How to find a string of multiple line in shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672791/how-to-find-a-string-of-multiple-line-in-shell-script). Is that JSON btw? if so, a dedicated JSON tool may be more appropriate.

Comment: use `grep -z` as `-z` will treat your content as 1 string, negating /n and /r

Comment: Thanks but it still can't do what I want.

Comment: I tried `grep -ilrz -e "snapshot3"*: { "@custom_name" : true* contains_snapshot3/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the string in a variable, and then use `grep -z` (the `-z` essentially makes `grep` treat the file as one large string) to search the file for it:

```
$ read -r -d '' var<<'EOF'  
  "snapshot3" : {
    "@custom_name" : true
EOF
$ grep -Fz "$var" file
```

Another is to build a regular expression that matches that string. For example:

```
grep -zP '\s*"snapshot3" : {\n\s*"@custom_name" : true' file
```

Comment: thanks a lot terdon, the second solution does the trick !